# CSS div overlaps, mouse event not recognized below it

Tags: css, html, hover, mouseevent

I'm creating a webpage-head that contains a menu. The menu's background-color differs from the heads' background-color and in order to have the desired box-shadow on the full head, I created a child-div that fills the whole area of the parent-div and added the box-shadow to it.

The problem is, that mouse events are not recognized any more as there is a div above it. How can I achieve that I can still hover and click on the menu?

*http://jsfiddle.net/5u9yy/1/* - http://jsfiddle.net/5u9yy/13/

PS: I greatly appreciate tips on how to improve the HTML and CSS layout.
PS 2: Bizarre, it looked grate in Firefox itself, but with the JSFiddle wrapped around it some issues appear.. (ul height, head-width)

*Edit*: Added updated paste *13* where the ul is not transparent for better demonstration purpose. The box-shadow must be rendered on top of the ul!

**Solution (thanks to TheWaxMan):**
Instead of adding a div *above* everything to add the inset box shadow, we can give the `ul` a box shadow. To get the effect right, put an additional parameter to the box shadow property which offses it to the inner of the element and move the box shadow down accordingly.

```
/*          mode  offset-x offset-y blur offset-inner color */
box-shadow: inset 0        10px     10px -10px        #000;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated this for you. Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/5u9yy/15/) I have set position: relative on the ul because the z-index property only works when the position is set. I have then set the z-index of the ul to 2 and of the div to 1 so it is rendered behind the ul.

EDIT: I have made a couple more changes to the css. As it stands there are 4 extra lines added. position & z-index on the ul, box-shadow on the li and z-index on the div. It now looks like the box shadow from the div blends into the links. Slightly messier than the first solution, but it works.

Comment: I always wondered why setting of `z-index` doesn't always work, thanks. xD Anyway, this does fix the events, but that way I wouldn't need the `<div class="headOverall></div>` because I could set the box-shadow to the `<div id="head">..</div>`. The box-shadow renderes behind the `ul` using the `z-index`. *Set the background-color of the ul to be less transparent to see the effect more clearly*

Comment: I see. Have you tried also adding a box-shadow to the inside of the li? Have a look at this one and see what you think: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/5u9yy/14/)

Comment: Ignore the last one, it was only on the hover. I have altered it now and made it only along the top. This should do it [fiddle rev 15](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/5u9yy/15/)

Comment: @TheWaxMann That's perfect. That actually doesn't require the `div.headOverall`, I didn't know about the additional argument you set to `-3px` on `box-shadow`. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, do you know how I can make the header scale over the full width? It stops at the width of the screen, but the site is larger and the header doesn't scale .. :/ Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is because you have floated the list to the right. A div that has floated content does not realise how wide the floated content is. The only way I am aware of dealing with this is to set the width to a pixel value instead of 100%

Answer (score 1):

Nice looking.

All I did is do some shuffling of the divs to nest them, rather than causing them to be positioned one over the top of the other.  This is cleaner than having the absolute positioning.

Changed headOverall to sort of a "container" of the menu stuffs, changed it to position relative, and voila.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnJQ9/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but same as above. It might not be very noticeable, but the box-shadow still renders behind the `ul`. I should've increased the semi-transparence for demonstration purpose, I think .. ;)